# Align according to text in GridLayout :kivy

Tags: python, kivy

iam trying to show the some text right side and some text in left side

> here is what i tried :-

```
from kivy.app import App,runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import ImageOps, ImageDraw
from PIL import Image as img
from kivy.uix.image import Image, AsyncImage
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage, Texture
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label
class m(App):
    def build(self):
        f=FloatLayout()
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        # Make sure the height is such that there is something to scroll.
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        list=[('hhhhbjjggjgjgii',' '),(' ','hgghughuffooeoeo'),(' ','hgghughuffooeoeo'),(' ','hgghughuffooeoeo'),('hhhhbjjggjgjgii\nvhhge\nshh',' '),(' ','hgghughuf\nfooeoeo'),('hhhhbjjggjgjgii',' '),(' ','hgghughuffooeoeo'),('hhhhbjjggjgjgii',' '),(' ','hgghughuffooeoeo'),('hhhhbjj\nggjgjgii',' '),(' ','hgghughuf\nsjsjfooeoeo'),('hhhhbjjg\ngg\nfgg\ngg\ngjgjgii',' '),(' ','hgghughuffooeoeo'),('hhhhbjjggjgjgii',' '),(' ','ab'),('hhhhbjjggjgjgii',' '),(' ','hgghughuffooeoeo')]
        for ifu in list:
            g=GridLayout(cols=2,rows=1,size_hint_y=None,spacing=200)
            if ifu[1]=='ab':
                l=Label(text=' ')
                g.add_widget(l)
                t=Button(background_normal='person-light.png',background_down='person-light.png',size_hint=(1,1))
                g.add_widget(t)
            else:
                if ifu[0]==' ':
                    l=Label(text=' ')
                    g.add_widget(l)
                    ime=Button(text='[color=ffffff]'+ifu[1]+'[/color]',markup=True,size_hint_y=None)
                    g.add_widget(ime)
                else:
                    ime=Button(text='[color=ffffff]'+ifu[0]+'[/color]',markup=True,size_hint_y=None)
                    g.add_widget(ime)
                    l=Label(text=' ')
                    g.add_widget(l)
            layout.add_widget(g)
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height-100))
        root.add_widget(layout)
        f.add_widget(root)
        return f
m().run()
```

but it isn't adjusting widtch and hight according to text, i want it to if text is small then width and height of button is also small, and if it is possible make that button rounded at corner's
pls help me out this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the size of a `Button` (or `Label`) by using its `texture_size`. You can use:

```
size_hint: None, None
size: self.texture_size
```

for a `Button` or `Label`, but that make the `Button` just big enough to hold the `text`. You can add a few pixels to provide a small space around the text like this in `kv`:

```
<MyButt>:
    size_hint: None, None
    height: self.texture_size[1] + 10
    width: self.texture_size[0] + 10
```

Then in the python code:

```
class MyButt(Button):
    pass
```

So just load the `kv` string above and replace usages of `Button` with `MyButt`.

You can get rounded buttons by using something like `MDFillRoundFlatButton` in `KivyMD`.

Comment: but if the button is bigger than the gridlayout its overlaying on ther buttons, i want to make the g(gridlayout) size to be same as button size

Comment: Not sure I understand. Could you show an example of the overlaying?

Comment: @i got it by kivy support but thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

by @John Anderson and to adjust the height of GridLayout that of the button i used height: self.minimum_height to avoid overlapping for big buttons